# IE9: How to load a site-specific style sheet

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9

Using IE7 on XP, I could load site-specific style sheets using a CSS expression to write the link to the CSS appropriate for the site and then calling the CSS 'wrapper' using IE's accessibility options. Now that I've advanced to IE9 on W7, this doesn't work any longer.

I spend 90% of my browsing time on three or four sites. On one, I have to change the colours of unvisited and visited links to be able to distinguish between them. On another, I have to increase the size of the body font to be able to read any text at the site, and so on. As it is, I have to change the accessibility options for each site, which means I can't just tab from a page on one site to a page on another. Is there no way of accomplishing this in IE9? A bit like the 'Stylish' plugin I've read about for Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it's more of a user issue, and might better belong on SuperUser.  However, you should be able to use something like [IE7 Pro](http://www.ie7pro.com/) to create user scripts to adapt pages to whatever yuo need.  This is sort of like Greasemonkey for Firefox.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I can't quite reconcile _it's more of a user issue_ with _use something ... to create user scripts_. I need a bit of help with writing and implementing a script to achieve the aim, if it's possible. Doesn't that count?

IE7Pro died with IE7 several years ago...

Comment: @Firedog - there was a version released just last year.. I don't see how it could have died several years ago.

Answer (score 0):

for my project I once rendered IE9 as IE8 by rendering it with meta tag of html

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8"/>
```

so the same css worked for both